# Access missing value in form.cleaned_data

Tags: django, django-forms

I was trying to dynamically generate fields as shown in http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/. My case slightly differs in that I am looking to use  multiplechoicefield that is dynamically created. This is what I came up with...

views.py

```
def browseget(request):
    success = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_form = ListForm(request.POST)
        if list_form.is_valid():
            success = True
            path = list_form.cleaned_data['path']
            minimum_size = list_form.cleaned_data['minimum_size']
            follow_link = list_form.cleaned_data['follow_link']
            checkboxes = list_form.cleaned_data['checkboxes']
            ....do something
    else:
        list_form = ListForm(name_list)
    ctx = {'success': success, 'list_form': list_form, 'path': path, 'minimum_size': minimum_size}
    return render_to_response('photoget/browseget.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class ListForm(forms.Form):
    path = forms.CharField(required=False)
    minimum_size = forms.ChoiceField(choices=size_choices)
    follow_link = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        name_list = kwargs.pop('name_list', None)
        super(ListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'Received data:', self.data
        if name_list:
            name_choices = [(u, u) for u in name_list]
            self.fields['checkboxes'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, label='Select Name(s):', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=name_choices)

    def clean_path(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        path = cd.get('path')
        if path == '': path = None
        return path

    def clean_minimum_size(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        minimum_size = cd.get('minimum_size')
        if minimum_size is None: minimum_size = 0
        return int(minimum_size)
```

The form generates and displays perfectly... until I post some data. The 'checkboxes' field doesn't show up in list_form.cleaned_data.items() while it shows in self.data. As it is the form breaks with a KeyError exception. So Im asking, how do i access the checkboxes data?

Comment: You've got a period between `cleaned_data` and `[checkboxes]` in your code. That'll lead to a syntax error which will prevent the post-conditional code from running successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing in the `name_list` parameter when you re-instantiate the form on POST, so the field is not created because `if name_list` is False.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you've got now? The thing is, the current code you have posted won't even create the checkboxes field in the first place, since you're not passing `name_list` as a kwarg.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. The issue was in passing the name_list variable since it was being defined out of the function scope. Overcame scope by making name_list a value in a dict.